# Should I write about my settlement with government employer

Tags: discrimination, previous-employer

I recently negotiated an out of court settlement for discrimination and retaliation with my former employer, a state agency. I am free to say whatever I want as a part of the settlement, but I am afraid this will look like badmouthing my former employer (I resigned as a part of the settlement). I am torn because the employer is a state government agency, so voters need to know the facts. I think writing an op ed would be the outlet/audience.

Comment: VTC - I don't think this is a Workplace question, fundamentally it's a Politics question - since it's about the Voters and the State agency.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to run for public office or continue in the private sector.

Comment: Are you permanently retired? If yes, then have at it. If not, then be careful. The last thing you want is an HR person who googles your name and finds this article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a piece were to gain traction (or even feature prominently in a Google search of your name) then it may have an impact on your prospects.

Some will view it negatively, to the extent where they actually take the opposing view to you - these aren't really a problem since it's doubtful you'd want to work for them anyway. You can see this as the trash taking itself out as it were.

Some will be wary, viewing you as someone who might be a problem employee, even if they agree you were in the right some employers would take the position that such matters should be handled quietly, without ruckus, and without putting the proverbial boot in after the fact.

Some will view it positively, an employee who isn't afraid to stand up for themselves and what's right is valued in some quarters.

If you do decide to write about it there's a couple of things I'd have in mind while you did so - firstly, whatever you put "out there" on the Internet is functionally there forever. Make sure you're as willing to stand by every word 5, 10, 15 years from now. Secondly keep it as impersonal as possible, when you talk about what was wrong talk about behaviour or policies **not** individuals

Answer (score 4):

What do you expect the possible employer's reaction to be? I would worry that "this guy sounds like he might be hard to work with if we ever disagree" might trump "this guy stood up for what he thought was right."

Be prepared to discuss it if they bring it up, or if it's really the best answer for a question... But I wouldn't mention it unless they put it on the table.

Comment: This is the right answer. Only the OP can decide if the potential risk is worth the benefit of letting the voters know (or even if the voters will care)

Comment: @mattfreake the right answer would be to close this Q and ask it again in Politics.

Answer (score 3):

> voters need to know the facts

I doubt this is true. The question is "why"?

If certain agencies are continually getting sued, and productivity suffers, that will reflect poorly on politicians. If they even care about public perception.

Regardless of all this, you write an op ed, that's what people are going to find when they search your name on the internet. You'll be seen as a trouble-maker for some employers.

I recommend you take the money and simply move on with your life. If it's any solace, you can hope that the bad apples have paid a price.